# nm and addr2line function address does not match

Tags: c

I have the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

#define BACKTRACE_SIZE 10

void log()
{
    void *array[BACKTRACE_SIZE];
    int s =0;
    s = backtrace(array, BACKTRACE_SIZE);
    for (int j=1; j<s; j++)
        fprintf(stdout," %p ", array[j]);
    fprintf(stdout,"\n");
}
void show_1()
{
    log();
}
void show_2()
{
    log();
}
void show_3()
{
    log();
}
void show_4()
{
    log();
}
int main (void)
{
    show_1();
    show_2();
    show_3();
    show_4();
}
```

When I compile and run it I get the below output:

```
~ 1064> a.out
 0x4006dd  0x4006e9  0x2ab130eec994  0x400599
 0x4006d1  0x4006ee  0x2ab130eec994  0x400599
 0x4006c5  0x4006f3  0x2ab130eec994  0x400599
 0x4006b9  0x4006f8  0x2ab130eec994  0x400599
```

However when I use nm utility to dump a function address say 'show_1()' I get:

```
~ 1070>  nm -S a.out | grep show_1 | c++filt
00000000004006d4 000000000000000b T show_1()
~ 1071>
```

However from the program stdout dump that I get the below output and run addr2line utility on it:

```
~ 1067> addr2line -Cfe ./a.out 0x4006dd  0x4006e9  0x2ab130eec994  0x400599
show_1()
??:0
main
??:0
??
??:0
_start
??:0
```

Further :

```
~ 1072> addr2line -Cfe ./a.out 0X4006d4 0x4006dd
show_1()
??:0
show_1()
??:0
```

The first output is from nm and other from the program.

Now in actual I have a bigger code facing the same problem. The backtraces are huge (data wise) and I cannot go and dump addr2line output for all backtraces. I need a particular function address to search in backtraces log generated and then use addr2line upon it occurances.

How can I get a particular function address which matches to the address generated by backtrace()/nm system/binutils call/utility?

Answer (score 2):

The addresses in a backtrace aren't the entry points of a function; they're the call sites (so they're addresses *within* a function).  This is just the nature of a backtrace.

The address shown by `nm` is the address of the function name symbol, which is the entry point of the function.

Comment: Is there a method to find entry point address using the address of call sites as generated by backtrace? Even printing function address using __cyg_profile_func_enter, __builtin_return_address(x) is not helping me here. They differ with output of nm.

Comment: @Prakash: Well, if the function is laid out linearly, not inlined etc then call sites within that function will be between the function entry point and the next function entry point.  But if you want a generic working solution then you should probably just process the entire backtrace with `addr2line()` and search for the functions you're interested in in the output.

Comment: One quick method I found is using --print-size option in nm utility. Add to the output I get without option in nm utility – I get the function start/end address.  Next get the first common address characters in between the two outputs and search it in the large backtrace file. As I find each occurrences I do addr2line() on each until I get what I am looking for. Though it is a time spending hard work I am still searching for a better alternative. Thanks.